# Angular Testing - trigger on change not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

I have a directive that I'm trying to unit test that includes an on 'change' event:

```
iElement.on 'change', (evt) ->
          scope.$apply () ->
            scope.model.user.data.roles = iElement.val()
```

Here is my code for the main test, which initializes scope.model and then tries to change it.

```
it 'modifies the existing role - INCOMPLETE', () ->
      scope.model = user: data: roles: Object.keys user.data.roles
      scope.$broadcast 'event:gotUser'
      scope.model.user.data.roles = ['Pizza']
      scope.$digest()
      element.triggerHandler('change')
      console.log(element.text())
```

Unfortunately, the 'change' event is not getting triggered and the value that is being returned by the directive is the old one: *'  Delicious×Delicious'*

## **Update**

**Fixed directive:**

```
compiled = $compile '<div <select heli-tag-control multiple="" style="width : 100%;"> </select></div>'
```

to

```
compiled = $compile '<div heli-tag-control multiple="" style="width : 100%;"> </div>'
```

**Updated test:**

```
it 'modifies the existing role - INCOMPLETE', () ->
      scope.model = user: data: roles: Object.keys user.data.roles
      scope.$broadcast 'event:gotUser'
      scope.model = user: data: roles: ['Happy', 'Banana']
      element.val(scope.model.user.data.roles).triggerHandler('change')
      expect(element.text()).to.contain 'Banana'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I just needed to broadcast my 'gotUser' event again and then the changes propagated.

**Complete Test:**

```
it 'modifies the existing role - INCOMPLETE', () ->
      scope.model = user: data: roles: Object.keys user.data.roles
      scope.$broadcast 'event:gotUser'
      scope.model = user: data: roles: ['Happy', 'Banana']
      element.val(scope.model.user.data.roles).triggerHandler('change')
      scope.$broadcast 'event:gotUser'
      expect(element.text()).to.contain 'Banana'
```